# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Forbidden SendGrid WebAPI error

Tags: node.js, sendgrid, webapi

//error//

(node:38736) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Reference Error: error is not defined

//code//

const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail')

const sendgridAPIKey = 'SG.xxxxx'

sgMail.setApiKey(sendgridAPIKey)

sgMail.send({
    to: email,
    from: 'xxx@gmail.com',
    subject: 'Thanks for joining in',
    text: 'Welcome to the app'
    })

Comment: Can you provide more information about what you're trying to accomplish and code snippets of where this error happened?

Answer (score 0):

`send()` method returns promise, you should `await` it. OR use `then()`

```
sgMail
    .send({ to: email, from: 'xxx@gmail.com', subject: 'Thanks for joining in', text: 'Welcome to the app' })
    .then(() => { }, error => {
        console.error(error);
    });
```